# Disable cronjob after reboots

Tags: ubuntu, cron, reboot

How can I prevent cronjobs from automatically starting after my server has rebooted?

Every time I reboot my server the cronjobs start up again, which I'd like to prevent.

These servers are running Ubuntu 12.04 x32

Comment: Why have cron jobs at all if you don't want them to run? (I probably don't understand your question.)

Comment: I still use them , but do not want them to start up until I say so (as is the case with server reboot).

Comment: Disable the cron daemon's startup script then?

Comment: Yep, that's why I have this question here! ... how is that done?

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, Ubuntu uses `anacron`, which by design runs cron jobs that were missed due to downtime, presumably to make cron jobs more reliable on laptops and other systems that are expected to be turned off more often than servers typically are.

If you don't wish this behavior, switch to another `cron` daemon that is not designed to run missed scheduled tasks.

Comment: Maybe you could explain to him how to disable this service as part of your answer? Try and be specific and show examples.

Comment: I only known anacron from CentOS. Can`t you just configure anacron in Ubuntu so it behaves more like the classical cron?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a very hacky method:

Comment out all cronjob lines:

```
echo "$(crontab -l)" | sed -e "s/^/#/g" | crontab
```

Uncomment out all cronjob lines:

```
echo "$(crontab -l)" | sed -e "s/#//g" | crontab
```

This way, if I reboot, it's commented out for when the cronjobs start up again.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer from [**Ask Ubuntu**](https://askubuntu.com/a/43579) is still valid.

On CentOS cron has been removed in favour of anacron - but it works a little bit different there. On Ubuntu:

It burns down to - imho - uninstall anacron. This will remove the anacron binary putting cron into "normal" mode without anacron kicking in.